# Chess using pygame

Tags: python, beginner

I just completed my second python project which is a chess game.
At the moment I have included a mechanism for pieces to lock onto a square based on the nearest square when moved. And I have introduced a mechanism to take pieces. I haven't yet checked for legal moves but I plan on doing that soon.

If anyone could suggest ways I could make the code neater/more effecient that would be greatly appreciated. I've been programming in C++ for around one and a half years so a few things I tried in python that I can do in C++ didn't work which caused me to do some unorthodox methods

If you want to run the project here are the images I used as a rar file
https://gofile.io/d/Ss0vPc

```
import pygame
import python_math as math

whiteC = (200,200,200)
blackC = (55, 55, 55)

class Coordinates: #convering pixel values to alpha and numerical values that you would see on a chess board
    # x values
    a = 0 * 100
    b = 1 * 100
    c = 2 * 100
    d = 3 * 100
    e = 4 * 100
    f = 5 * 100
    g = 6 * 100
    h = 7 * 100
    i = 8 * 100
    j = 9 * 100
    k = 10 * 100 
    l = 11 * 100 
    m = 12 * 100 
    n = 13 * 100 

    # y values
    one = 7 * 100
    two = 6 * 100
    three = 5 * 100
    four = 4 * 100
    five = 3 * 100
    six = 2 * 100
    seven = 1 * 100
    eight = 0 * 100

c = Coordinates

whiteTAC = [(c.i, c.eight), (c.j, c.eight) , (c.k, c.eight), (c.l, c.eight), (c.m, c.eight), (c.n, c.eight), (c.i, c.seven), 
            (c.j, c.seven), (c.k, c.seven), (c.l, c.seven), (c.m, c.seven), (c.n, c.seven), (c.i, c.six), (c.j, c.six),
           (c.k, c.six), (c.l, c.six)] # when we take a piece, these are the coordinates in which the taken piece will go to

blackTAC = [(c.i, c.one), (c.j, c.one) , (c.k, c.one), (c.l, c.one), (c.m, c.one), (c.n, c.one), (c.i, c.two), 
            (c.j, c.two), (c.k, c.two), (c.l, c.two) , (c.m, c.two), (c.n, c.two), (c.i, c.three), (c.j, c.three),
           (c.k, c.three), (c.l, c.three)]

def round100bottom(x):
    return int(math.math.floor(x / 100.0)) * 100
def round100top(x):
    return int(math.math.ceil(x / 100.0)) * 100

class game_logic:
    currentMove = "white"
    wI = 0 #indexs used for moving a piece when its taken away, used for arrays whiteTAC and blackTAC
    bI = 0

GL = game_logic
 
class Piece:
    
    side = None
    image = None
    coords = None
    heldDown = False
    tempCoords = coords
    tempBool = False
    finalRoundOne = 0
    finalRoundTwo = 0
    justMoved = False


    def __init__(self, image, coords, side):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.coords = coords
        self.side = side


    def listenForMovement(self, event):      
        print(self.side)
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if self.justMoved:
                print("called")
                if GL.currentMove == "white":
                    GL.currentMove = "black"
                else:
                    GL.currentMove = "white"
                self.justMoved = False

                self.heldDown = False
                self.tempBool = False

                if ((self.coords[0] - round100bottom(self.coords[0])) < 50): # tests to see which square is the closest by rounding the top and the bottom and seeing which is smallest
                    self.finalRoundOne = round100bottom(self.coords[0])
                else:
                    self.finalRoundOne = round100top(self.coords[0])

                if ((self.coords[1] - round100bottom(self.coords[1])) < 50):
                    self.finalRoundTwo = round100bottom(self.coords[1])
                else:
                    self.finalRoundTwo = round100top(self.coords[1])


            
                self.coords = (self.finalRoundOne, self.finalRoundTwo)
                TakePiece(self.coords, self.side)
    
        if ((event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN or self.heldDown == True) and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > self.coords[0] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < self.coords[0] + 100 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > self.coords[1] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < self.coords[1] + 100 and GL.currentMove == self.side):
            self.heldDown = True
            if self.tempBool != True:
                self.tempCoords = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - self.coords[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - self.coords[1])
                self.tempBool = True
            self.coords = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - self.tempCoords[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - self.tempCoords[1])
            self.justMoved = True

                   
class White:
    king        = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wking.png', (c.e, c.one), "white")
    queen       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wqueen.png', (c.d, c.one), "white")
    bishop1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wbishop.png', (c.c, c.one), "white")
    bishop2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wbishop.png', (c.f, c.one), "white")
    knight1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wknight.png', (c.b, c.one), "white")
    knight2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wknight.png', (c.g, c.one), "white")
    castle1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wcastle.png', (c.a, c.one), "white")
    castle2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wcastle.png', (c.h, c.one), "white")
    pawn1       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.a, c.two), "white")
    pawn2       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.b, c.two), "white")
    pawn3       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.c, c.two), "white")
    pawn4       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.d, c.two), "white")
    pawn5       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.e, c.two), "white")
    pawn6       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.f, c.two), "white");
    pawn7       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.g, c.two), "white")
    pawn8       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\wpawn.png', (c.h, c.two), "white")

class Black:
    king        = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bking.png', (c.e, c.eight), "black")
    queen       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bqueen.png', (c.d, c.eight), "black")
    bishop1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bbishop.png', (c.c, c.eight), "black")
    bishop2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bbishop.png', (c.f, c.eight), "black")
    knight1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bknight.png', (c.b, c.eight), "black")
    knight2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bknight.png', (c.g, c.eight), "black")
    castle1     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bcastle.png', (c.a, c.eight), "black")
    castle2     = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bcastle.png', (c.h, c.eight), "black")
    pawn1       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.a, c.seven), "black")
    pawn2       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.b, c.seven), "black")
    pawn3       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.c, c.seven), "black")
    pawn4       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.d, c.seven), "black")
    pawn5       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.e, c.seven), "black")
    pawn6       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.f, c.seven), "black")
    pawn7       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.g, c.seven), "black")
    pawn8       = Piece(r'C:\sprites\bpawn.png', (c.h, c.seven), "black")


  
pygame.init()
dis = pygame.display.set_mode((1400, 800))
pygame.display.update()

white = White
black = Black
def draw_pieces():
   # dis.blit(white.king.image, white.king.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn1.image, white.pawn1.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn2.image, white.pawn2.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn3.image, white.pawn3.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn4.image, white.pawn4.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn5.image, white.pawn5.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn6.image, white.pawn6.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn7.image, white.pawn7.coords)
    dis.blit(white.pawn8.image, white.pawn8.coords)

    dis.blit(white.king.image, white.king.coords)
    dis.blit(white.queen.image, white.queen.coords)
    dis.blit(white.bishop1.image, white.bishop1.coords)
    dis.blit(white.bishop2.image, white.bishop2.coords)
    dis.blit(white.knight1.image, white.knight1.coords)
    dis.blit(white.knight2.image, white.knight2.coords)
    dis.blit(white.castle1.image, white.castle1.coords)
    dis.blit(white.castle2.image, white.castle2.coords)

    dis.blit(black.pawn1.image, black.pawn1.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn2.image, black.pawn2.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn3.image, black.pawn3.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn4.image, black.pawn4.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn5.image, black.pawn5.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn6.image, black.pawn6.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn7.image, black.pawn7.coords)
    dis.blit(black.pawn8.image, black.pawn8.coords)

    dis.blit(black.king.image, black.king.coords)
    dis.blit(black.queen.image, black.queen.coords)
    dis.blit(black.bishop1.image, black.bishop1.coords)
    dis.blit(black.bishop2.image, black.bishop2.coords)
    dis.blit(black.knight1.image, black.knight1.coords)
    dis.blit(black.knight2.image, black.knight2.coords)
    dis.blit(black.castle1.image, black.castle1.coords)
    dis.blit(black.castle2.image, black.castle2.coords)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        white.king.listenForMovement(event)
        white.queen.listenForMovement(event)
        white.bishop1.listenForMovement(event)
        white.bishop2.listenForMovement(event)
        white.castle1.listenForMovement(event)
        white.castle2.listenForMovement(event)
        white.knight1.listenForMovement(event)
        white.knight2.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn1.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn2.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn3.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn4.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn5.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn6.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn7.listenForMovement(event)
        white.pawn8.listenForMovement(event)

        black.king.listenForMovement(event)
        black.queen.listenForMovement(event)
        black.bishop1.listenForMovement(event)
        black.bishop2.listenForMovement(event)
        black.castle1.listenForMovement(event)
        black.castle2.listenForMovement(event)
        black.knight1.listenForMovement(event)
        black.knight2.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn1.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn2.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn3.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn4.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn5.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn6.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn7.listenForMovement(event)
        black.pawn8.listenForMovement(event)

def TakePiece(coords, side):
    if side == "black":
        if white.king.coords == coords:
            white.king.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.queen.coords == coords:
            white.queen.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.king.coords == coords:
            white.king.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.queen.coords == coords:
            white.queen.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.castle1.coords == coords:
            white.castle1.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.castle2.coords == coords:
            white.castle2.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.knight1.coords == coords:
            white.knight1.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.knight2.coords == coords:
            white.knight2.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.bishop1.coords == coords:
            white.bishop1.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.bishop2.coords == coords:
            white.bishop2.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn1.coords == coords:
            white.pawn1.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn2.coords == coords:
            white.pawn2.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn3.coords == coords:
            white.pawn3.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn4.coords == coords:
            white.pawn4.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn5.coords == coords:
            white.pawn5.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn6.coords == coords:
            white.pawn6.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn7.coords == coords:
            white.pawn7.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
        if white.pawn8.coords == coords:
            white.pawn8.coords = whiteTAC[GL.wI]
            GL.wI += 1
    if side == "white":
        if black.king.coords == coords:
            black.king.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.queen.coords == coords:
            black.queen.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.king.coords == coords:
            black.king.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.queen.coords == coords:
            black.queen.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.castle1.coords == coords:
            black.castle1.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.castle2.coords == coords:
            black.castle2.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.knight1.coords == coords:
            black.knight1.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.knight2.coords == coords:
            black.knight2.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.bishop1.coords == coords:
            black.bishop1.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.bishop2.coords == coords:
            black.bishop2.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn1.coords == coords:
            black.pawn1.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn2.coords == coords:
            black.pawn2.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn3.coords == coords:
            black.pawn3.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn4.coords == coords:
            black.pawn4.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn5.coords == coords:
            black.pawn5.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn6.coords == coords:
            black.pawn6.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn7.coords == coords:
            black.pawn7.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1
        if black.pawn8.coords == coords:
            black.pawn8.coords = blackTAC[GL.bI]
            GL.bI += 1

    
def draw_background():
    pygame.draw.rect(dis, (180, 180, 180), [800, 0, 600, 800])
    for i in range(0, 8):
        for j in range(0, 8):
            if (i + j) % 2 != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(dis, blackC, [i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100 ])
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(dis, whiteC, [i * 100, j * 100, 100, 100 ])

 

def main():
    

    while True:
        draw_background()
        draw_pieces() 

        pygame.display.update()



main()
```